# IncludeFilter inGeneric Repository

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-plus

I need filter in includes also. I have Record Status in all tables. So i need to filter the records based on this. To accommodate this, I am using [Z.EntityFramework.Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/)'s [IncludeFilter](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/wiki/EF-Query-IncludeFilter-%7C-Entity-Framework-Include-Related-Entities-using-Where-Filter#ef-query-IncludeFilter) method.

**My generic data code below;**

```
    public async Task<T> GetAsync(int id, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
    {
        var query = _context.Set<T>().AsQueryable(); //.FindAsync(id);

        if (includes.Length > 0)
        {
            query = includes.Aggregate(query,
              (current, include) => current.IncludeFilter(include));
        }
        var item = await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
        return item;
    }
```

When i include where condition from the calling method (business class) its working fine. But i don't want to include these where condition in all places. So i need to change this method to include the where condition hereitself.

Please help me to do. I didn't get any where extension in my include parameter

*Note: I need to include where condition in each of the include.*

Comment: I don't understand how this isn't working for you. Can you explain what the problem is?

Comment: sorry for my poor english. The code working fine if i include where class in the calling method. I mean in my business layer. But i need change this generic method to include where condition here itself. So no need to add where condition in all business classes

Comment: Do you want to include this condition for ALL queries? Or how do you know when it should be added or not?

Comment: yes my where condition is checking record status which should add in all includes. So i thinking to add in this general repository method itself

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you could make all of your entity types implement an interface (`IRecord`?) with the `RecordStatus` property on it.

Then you could change your includes parameter to `Expression<Func<T, IRecord>>[]`.

The tricky part would be to construct new `include` expressions, based on the ones you're given, adding an `&& r.RecordStatus == "whatever"` onto each of them. The code to do something like that can be a little ugly, but it should be possible.

Comment: i got it. yes we have an interface for entities which is IEntity. But how can i create new expression in generic method itself and assign back to the existing includes

Comment: @Akhil: It's complicated enough that I don't have time to put together a code sample for you, but you can learn about building Expression trees [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/).